# How to get simple decimal arithmetic right?

Tags: python, math, floating-point

I know that computing decimals is not an easy task for a computer, but is there any way I can get simple arithmetic get done in python? What is the best approach?

```
>>> 0.3 + 0.3 + 0.3 + 0.1 != 1
True
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(0.3) + Decimal(0.3) + Decimal(0.3) + Decimal(0.1) != 1
True
>>> Decimal(0.3) + Decimal(0.3) + Decimal(0.3) + Decimal(0.1) != Decimal(1)
True
>>> Decimal(0.3) + Decimal(0.3) + Decimal(0.3) + Decimal(0.1)
Decimal('0.9999999999999999722444243843')
```

**Update:**

As proposed, the solution would be to use `Decimal()` and strings instead of plain numbers. But I find this solution very unsatisfying (non pythonic and ugly). Really there is no other way? (using a decorator perhaps?)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: That is incorrect. As the answer here and in the other referenced question shows, you can use decimal arithmetic, and the correction to the OP’s code is to use strings to initialize decimal values, not binary floating-point constants.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Yes, we know binary floating-point is not accurate for decimal arithmetic. How is that helpful for this question? The OP already knows there is an inaccuracy, so you have not provided any new information.

Comment: Regarding your update: (a) You can assign your constants to named variables so that you can use those nicer names in your code instead of repeating verbose constructions like `Decimal('0.3')`. (b) It is possible to use binary floating-point to get some decimal arithmetic done correctly, but it requires expert knowledge of floating-point. It is probably not the solution you want.

Comment: @vaultah All the other questions have the same solution, I am looking for something different. I think the community did not come out with a satisfying answer yet.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So assuming you wanted to check a floating point value against another one, you would import the decimal module and convert to str instead of just supplying a tolerance or checking it some other, non-floating point-dependent way..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: The OP does not ask about comparing one floating-point value to another.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Of course he is.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: The question asks about getting mathematically correct values for decimal arithmetic. The only comparison used is for the purpose of illustration of the exact value arrived at by arithmetic; there is no indication that comparing floating-point values is actually a component of their application. In any case, your comment “the best approach is not to depend on it” is incorrect (although it is unclear what the antecedent of your “it” is—floating-point? The Decimal package?). Floating-point arithmetic is dependable if you understand it, and it is useful.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Eric is right. I am asking how to get correct results from decimal arithmetic AND how to do it in a better way that converting everything to string and using ugly `Decimal()` calls. I really hope there is a better way. So far, no luck.

Comment: If `Decimal` were not the Pythonic way to exactly represent decimals in Python, then why would `Decimal` be part of Python?

Comment: @Sneftel `Decimal` is a function, they should have defined a proper decimal type like in Viper for example. I think they could have done something like `from future import decimal_type` and that all the floats in the script would have been of decimal type by default (same as they did with `division`). So, if I have 100 formulas in my code they would have just worked as expected without pushing me to add `Decimal()` and `""` all over the place. Unfortunately, the latter seems to be the only solution so far, and it is not pythonic at all.

Comment: Decimal *is* a type, not a function (try `type(Decimal("0.3"))`). As for replacing all floating point constants with decimal constants, that sounds like a *really* bad idea from a performance standpoint, but feel free to suggest it! See [PEP 1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/) for how.

Comment: @alec_djinn: "they should have defined a proper decimal type like in Viper for example" <- I'm curious. I'm looking at the viper source on GitHub, and I don't see anywhere that the arithmetic operations (e.g., multiplication, division) for the decimal type are defined. Can you point me to the right place?

Comment: @Mark Dickinson in types.py combine_units() I believe.

Comment: Also, in parser/parser_utils.py get_number_as_fraction()

Answer (score 3):

When you write `Decimal(0.3)` you're using a floating point value 0.3 which is subject to precision errors.

```
>>> Decimal(0.3)
Decimal('0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875')
```

Use strings to avoid floating point entirely.

```
>>> Decimal('0.3') + Decimal('0.3') + Decimal('0.3') + Decimal('0.1')
Decimal('1.0')
```

Comment: Why `Decimal(1)` would be different from `Decimal('1.0')` ? Isn't confusing?

Comment: Isn't there any other way to accomplish that without converting all numbers in strings? This solution is definitely not pythonic and unbelievably ugly.

Comment: @alec_djinn: `Decimal(1)` will have the same value as `Decimal('1.0')`, because binary floating-point does represent 1 exactly. `Decimal(0.3)` will not have the same value as `Decimal('0.3')` because binary floating-pont does not represent .3 exactly. So you could omit the apostrophes for `Decimal(1)`. But then you need to be clear in your code about when you can and cannot omit apostrophes; it is easy to forget and make a mistake. That especially so for another engineer who changes your code later and does not know why you used apostrophes in some places and not others.